# Plotting odd amounts of subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating a function where the user can choose the number of graphs they want to display per row.

here is my plotting function:

```
def some_func(input_values, graphs_to_show_per_row):

    figure, axes = plt.subplots(round(len(input_values)/graphs_to_show_per_row), graphs_to_show_per_row, figsize=(3,3))

    for value, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
        ax.plot(to_plot[value])
```

and these are the values I am going to plot

```
to_plot = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]
```

When I do:

```
some_func(to_plot,2)
```

The output is what I want, with two graphs per row. However, when I do:

```
some_func(to_plot,3)
```

It returns only 3 graphs and does not plot the fourth. I would like the fourth one to be plotted but on its own row by itself. So the first row will have 3 graphs, then the second row will only have the graph by itself.

Comment: What is `Xs` exactly?

Comment: Apologies, I have edited the code. It was meant to be the length of input_values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is caused due to rounding issues:

In the case `len(input_values) = 4` and you want `3` plot per row you get:

`round(len(input_values)/graphs_to_show_per_row) = 1` because `len(input_values)/graphs_to_show_per_row = 1.33`

In your case, you want to use `ceil` on floating-point division, and the adjustment to the code should be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def some_func(input_values, graphs_to_show_per_row):

    num_rows = math.ceil(float(len(input_values) / graphs_to_show_per_row))
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(num_rows, graphs_to_show_per_row, figsize=(3,3))

    for plt_, ax in zip(input_values ,axes.flatten()[:len(input_values)]):
        ax.plot(plt_)
    return

to_plot = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]
some_func(to_plot,3)
```

Notice the following line:

`for plt_, ax in zip(input_values ,axes.flatten()[:len(input_values)]):`

I want to make sure I plot only where I supposed to plot because some values like the ones passed to the function will create a grid with more plots than's possible due to the input.